# Did the US accidentally syndicalize its police force? (or something similar?)

Tags: united-states, police, syndicalism

Could the USA's police (or at least portions of it,) be considered a example of syndicalism?

While not entirely due to it, their union has been able to get them military equipment to use, lax training regulations, has helped them escape punishment for things like unreasonable use of force, and generally commands a lot of political influence(, ironically with the normally anti-union republicans more then their often pro-union democratic opposition.)

So ya, could you call the USA's police force a example of syndicalism in action? Seeing as a lot of this has to do with just how powerful their union has become; or would they need a corporate doppelganger to dominate for this label to stick?

Edit: Seeing as the police here aren't exactly syndicalized, let me be a bit broader: What qualities of syndicalism could be considered responsible for making the police into what they are now? and do they present some possible goods to go along with it's more visible bads?

Comment: I've done voted this because the U.S. police force is not a monolithic entity and the reference to syndicalism is misapplied.

Comment: Thank mate! (tho, I'd argue downvoting shouldn't be used for otherwise appropriate questions)

Comment: @DrunkCynic would your objections remain if we edited the question to read "its police forces" or "some of its police forces" or similar?

Comment: I think there is a false assumption here... the unions do not unilaterally make decisions. They need to negotiate contracts. And at the end of the day, you could technically just [fire them all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Air_Traffic_Controllers_Organization_(1968)).

Comment: @phoog In part; there is a good question in there somewhere, likely if it was more buck shot, less slug. "Have some Police forces in the US accidently adapted syndicalism?" Been chewing on the rough looking for a diamond since the comment. The question of whether syndicalism is applicable can be sorted by the answers.

Comment: Perhaps the law and order voting block is conflated with police unions. Presumably police often vote with them and may be the loudest voice in the movement, but I doubt police make a majority of people calling for more resources for police.

Answer (score -2):

> Could the USA's police (or at least portions of it,) be considered a example of syndicalism?

There are certainly elements of syndicalism in the police, naturally as a result of unionization. But the police unions are more into economics not how policing is carried out, generally speaking. And are certainly not into day to day operations of the police force.

Syndicalism is inevitable as you have strong unions, uaw, steel workers unions, teachers unions. And public employees unions. There is an inherent conflict of interest when public employees unions supported candidates negotiate with the unions for their pay and benefits. But that's a topic that we are not supposed to discuss.

Btw, unions didn't get the police force militarized. The federal government and criminals did that.

Comment: Without sources, your answer is mostly just your opinions.